# removing a ppa in ubuntu without using ppa-purge

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.10

I had used some third party PPAs to install OpenCV 2.3 on my Ubuntu 11.10. Now while upgrading I faced a few problems with these packages and their unmet dependencies. So I wanted to remove the ppas. But for that I'd be needing a package called ppa-purge which I cannot install now because my package structure seems to be broken.

Any workarounds for this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:PPA_Name/ppa
```

Replace "PPA_Name" with the name of your PPA.

Answer (score 3):

Edit  /etc/apt/sources.list  manually,  remove you problem url,  then apt-get update,  then coninue upgrading.

Comment: how do I find the problem URL?

Comment: @wrahool: just run "sudo apt-get update" and see which urls are causing issues from whatever is printed from the console, or which ones look familiar.  Usually ppas that are added reside in a file of their own in the directory above (for me it was /etc/apt/sources.list.d/<problem ppa file>.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing problems regarding Broken packages then first of all remove that package by first checking dependencies and then forcefully remove that package, and don't ever forget to reboot when you do make enormous changes in your system. To remove that package use these shell commands

```
$ sudo su
```

Then Enter your password

```
# apt-cache rdepends package-name
# apt-get --purge remove --force package-name
```

Use these shell commands

```
# apt-get clean
# apt-get autoclean
# apt-get update
# apt-get upgrade
# apt-get dist-upgrade
# reboot
```

This worked for me, Try this, I believe this will fix all your problems, Good luck.